# What does "1B63" mean in bash?

Tags: python, xterm, ansi-escape

When I print the string value of `0x1b63` in bash, the screen clear (exactly like `tput reset` result):
[image]

After pressing `Enter` button we have:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: It's called escape sequence. It controlls terminal behaviour when printed.

Comment: @DarthKotik Does it documented anywhere that `ESC + C` means _clear bash_?

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes this could help

Comment: The hex sequence `\x1b\x63` is ESCc, which is the [ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to reset the terminal to its initial state.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `bash`. You are using the Python interpreter.

Comment: Actually it's VT100 (not "ANSI" in the technical sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ANSI escape sequences. There's a list of some on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

`\x1b` means `ESC`
`\x63` is a lower case `c`

On that page `ESC` `c` is shown as

> RIS – Reset to Intitial State Resets the device to its original state. This may include (if applicable): reset graphic rendition, clear tabulation stops, reset to default font, and more.

so the terminal will clear. This isn't related to bash, or python, but the terminal that you're running in.